Multiprocess environement with stablebaseline3 SubprocVecEnv
I have a working (complex) Gymnasium environment that needs two processes to work properly, and I want to train an agent to accomplish some task in this environment.
To train the agent, I would like to use several environments in parallel using SubprocVecEnv from stablebaseline. Unfortunatly, it seems that SubprocVecEnv does not allow the creation of environments that have themselves multiple processes because it is based on daemon processes which are not allowed to have subprocesses (see this comment, from 1).
    # daemon=True: if the main process crashes, we should not cause things to hang
    process = ctx.Process(target=_worker, args=args, daemon=True)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

Indeed, if I run this code, it ends with this error:
AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Is there any clean workaround this ?
